# Android app - user communication through Firebase

Tags: android, firebase

I'm trying to add a feature in my Android app for users to be able to send custom objects (as JSONs I guess) between them. I am new to Firebase and user-to-user interactions and I've been reading through a few things and couple of codelabs about Firebase, but what I want is not a realtime database, nor a Whatsapp messaging styled implementation.

All I want to know, is what is the easiest way for user A to send something across to user B using Firebase? What Firebase product or practice should I be looking at?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use Firebase storage for this.
If User A wants to send a file to User B:

1. User A will upload a file to firebase storage and get a link to the file.
2. User A shares the link with User B.
3. User B will then download the file from firebase storage.

You can check out the documentation here: [Firebase storage docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/android/start)

Comment: Thanks! That's exactly what I needed! +1